# Sqlalchemy max by 2 columns

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I need to be able to perform min operation of 2 columns in `sqlalchemy`. These 2 columns could be from 2 different tables. Pure SQL analog of the operation would be:

```
Select Id,
       Case When Col1 < Col2 Then Col1
            Else Col2
            End As TheMin
From   TableName
```

I've been going through the docs and did not find a straightforward way to do that.
How this can be implemented in `sqlalchemy`?

Comment: Is your question for a specific RDBMS engine or must it be generic?

Comment: It must be generic, for all of the SQL connectors that sqlaclhemy manages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using a RDBMS which supports the functions `GREATEST` and `LEAST`, you should consider using them as they support more than 2 columns and handle correctly `NULL` values.
These include [postgresql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html), [mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least), DB, MariaDB and Oracle.

If you do need a custom 2 value comparison however, i would suggest you follow the ["GREATEST" function](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/compiler.html#greatest-function) example from the official documentation, which will allow you to use the function in a generic way - use the DB level function if the engine supports it, and custom implementation otherwise (sqlite, MS SQL etc).

*You should be careful, however, with cases where one value is NULL, which might not produce the desired result.*

In any event, the query you care about could be written as below:

```
least_clause = (
    sa.case(
        [(ModelA.val < ModelB.val, ModelA.val)],
        else_=ModelB.val,
    )
)

# query
q = (
    session
    .query(
        least_clause.label("TheMin"),
        least(ModelA.val, ModelB.val).label("custom-least"),  # this is if you use custom function from linked example
        sa.func.least(ModelA.val, ModelB.val).label("builtin-least"),  # only support for build-int LEAST function
        ModelA,
        ModelB,
    )
    .select_from(ModelA)
    .outerjoin(ModelB, ModelA.key == ModelB.key)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish this with `sqlalchemy.sql.expression.case`.

`from sqlalchemy import case`

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Case

```
stmt = select(table).\
            where(
                case(
                    (table.Col1 < table.Col2, table.Col1),
                    else_=table.Col2
                )
            )
```

If from two tables where you can't perform a join, a [subquery](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.subquery) should help.

Comment: Hm, I get "Operator 'getitem' is not supported on this expression" error.

Comment: @unresolved_external   It should be `case([(when clause)])` (note the square brackets).